# When selecting data from database and the condition is date, I receive this message that data type mismatches in criteria expression

Tags: c#, date, select, oledb, where-clause

When selecting data from the database and the condition is date, I receive this message that there is a data type mismatch in the criteria expression.

This is my code.

```
public DataTable loadhooodor()
{
    DataTable hooodorDt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter hooodorDa;
    hooodorDt.Clear();
    DateTime today = new DateTime();
    today = DateTime.Today;
    hooodorDa = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from HoodoorEnseraf where heDate='"+ today+ "'", connection);
    hooodorDa.Fill(hooodorDt);
    return hooodorDt;
}
```

and

```
private void dataGridRefresh()
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.Update();
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = loadhooodor();
}
```

I receive this message.

[image]

My access data table is,

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest using a parameter for the date instead of formatting the query so that it will properly handle the formatting for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refer to a date in Access you have to put `#` around it. [This link gives more details](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-Access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762#__toc358028377)

You will also want to make sure your date is formatted correctly. You can use `ToString` for this.

So your code becomes:

```
hooodorDa = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from HoodoorEnseraf where heDate=#"+ today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")+ "#", connection);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the problems with not using parametrized queries. Try this instead

```
hooodorDa = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from HoodoorEnseraf where heDate=@today", connection);
hooodorDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@today",
                System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
hooodorDa.SelectCommand.Parameters["@today"].Value = today;
hooodorDa.Fill(hooodorDt);
```

Answer (score 0):

check the date format of your system & the date format of the date you are sending in.

Comment: the same mm/dd/yyyy